# Providing bug report tool for a web application with screenshot capability?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I would really like to provide a bug report tool for a software I'm working on in PHP/JS. It would be beneficial to be able to take screenshots because users are not enough nerds to do print screen + paste and that's also painful for them.

Is there a way to take screenshots, say using HTML5 Canvas or something? Even if it works in some modern browsers it would help.

Comment: this answer can help you  [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like a drop-in solution, give Usersnap a try ( https://usersnap.com ) - installing is as simple as adding google analytics and the screenshots are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There is also couple of other tools for that. E.g. http://trackduck.com or http://bugherd.com

I tried all 3 tools, but stay with TrackDuck for easy of use and video feedback feature. From other hand I really do like painting arrows on UserSnap screenshots.